# How to parameterize snowflake account queries

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ddl

I'd like to paramaterize `accountName` in `create_account_query`. I can't get the query to insert the account name. Any ideas?

Running the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.execute(create_account_query,
  File "/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 695, in execute
    query = self._preprocess_pyformat_query(command, params)
  File "/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 594, in _preprocess_pyformat_query
    query = command % processed_params
ValueError: unsupported format character '?' (0xa) at index 37
```

```
import snowflake.connector
from snowflake.connector import DictCursor

create_account_query = """
    create managed account %(accountName)
        admin_name = %(username)s,
        admin_password = %(password)s,
        type = reader;
    """

with snowflake.connector.connect(account='xyz', user='myUser', password='myPass') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor(DictCursor)
    cursor.execute(create_account_query,
                   {'accountName': 'testAccount', 'username': 'test_user', 'password': 'test_pass'})
```

If I add the type to the parameter

```
create_account_query = """
    create managed account %(accountName)s
        admin_name = %(username)s,
        admin_password = %(password)s,
        type = reader;
    """
```

I get

```
Snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 23 unexpected ''testAccount''.
```

I noticed this behavior when creating other Snowflake objects, such as shares and warehouses.

Comment: you missedan s in `account %(accountName)` it must be `account %(accountName)s`

Comment: I mentioned this in the second part, and the error that it gives me. It works for the other fields though

Comment: i doubt that you can use parameters https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-managed-account mentions that name can only be enclosed in double quotes, som single quotes as introduced are causing the error